# Rails delayed_job - delayed job is deleted from table, in status running, but never finishes/executes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I am using `delayed_job` to schedule tasks which post to Facebook's open graph to circumvent issues with the content not being ready for Facebook's scrapers immediately after the action is completed. (scrapers get the wrong "og:type" content because it is not yet cached on Facebook's side)

As far as I can tell, I have the pieces for this workflow set up correctly. However, when the job is queued I can see from the server logs that it is inserted into the delayed_jobs table. When I query that delayed_job at the console, it doesn't exist (in fact none exist, they are always deleted). When checking `delayed_job.log` I can see the the job was logged as a status of `RUNNING` then never reports any further and by checking Facebook the job doesn't seem to have been executed. Previously I was receiving errors from Facebook indicating the action failed which was setting the jobs to a status of `FAILED`. Since that is not the case anymore I believe the action itself has been fixed.

The reporting in the server log is also erratic, as sometimes I can see logs of the delayed_job being deleted but sometimes it is deleted without a trace in the server log.

I can't figure out where to troubleshoot this or where to verify if the action is being executed as it should be. Relevant code below, please ask for any additional that's helpful.

**delayed_job.log output when method was getting Facebook errors**

```
Job JobScheduler::FacebookListCreation (id=2) FAILED (7 prior attempts) with NoMethodError: undefined method `list_url'
```

**delayed_job.log output after recreating method to fix Facebook error**

```
Job JobScheduler::PublishFBListCreation (id=15) RUNNING
```

**from calling controller**

```
if current_user.facebook_id && current_user.facebook_access_token
  Delayed::Job.enqueue JobScheduler::PublishFBListCreation.new(list_url(@list), current_user.facebook_access_token), 0, 1.minutes.from_now
end
```

**job_scheduler.rb**

```
class PublishFBListCreation < Struct.new(:full_list_url, :facebook_access_token)
  def perform
    @app = FbGraph::Application.new(ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], :secret => ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'])
    @fb_user = FbGraph::User.me(facebook_access_token)

    action = @fb_user.og_action!(
           @app.og_action(:create), :list => full_list_url)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your actual problem but one of your error "**undefined method `list_url'**" is because it belongs to your calling class and delayed job don't know about it. You can fix it like this:

```
if current_user.facebook_id && current_user.facebook_access_token
  url = list_url(@list)
  access_token = current_user.facebook_access_token
  Delayed::Job.enqueue JobScheduler::PublishFBListCreation.new(url, access_token), 0, 1.minutes.from_now
end
```

Comment: I don't think that should matter. That should be evaluated at call time and would be passed into the enqueue call as the evaluated value, ie the full URL.

The actual problem in shorter form is that the jobs get queued and go to a state of running but don't actually work.

Comment: where you get this list_url error in delayed job error column or in your logs?

Comment: It's the error reported along with the failure in the delayed_job.log file

Comment: then just give it a try I think so this is the problem

Comment: As I mentioned in the OP, this error is no longer an issue as it's no longer reported. If that was still erroring out, it would be reported in the logs still, correct?

Comment: I can see here from my server logs that the job is in fact created with the evaluated url: `["handler", "--- !ruby/struct:JobScheduler::PublishFBListCreation\nfull_list_url: http://dev.....:3000/lists/43\nfacebook_access_token: CAALO...`

Comment: then you can place some puts or logger in PublishFBListCreation class's perform method to verify is call reaches to that function or not.

Comment: Attempted some puts in the method itself. Since I don't see any server log output I would assume the job is being deleted from the database without actually running.

Comment: I am also facing same issue after rails upgrade. Did you find any solution? In my case also its adding entry in database. Showing RUNNING status on delayed_job log and then delete database entry after sometime without executing anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and realized I had one of the common problems listed here: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Common-problems